# Passing Fields From a Form To The Fields On a Website

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, communication

So I am just a hobby programmer that is self taught C# and currently designing my own application to reduce the amount of steps it requires to do stuff for my job and I have a Few things I would Like help with one thing is i would like to  create Fields that update a Internets Form I am not sure if this is do able even between 2 different languages.

[Website Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khtwC.jpg)

```
//When Button is Pressed Create The New Job In The Specified Location and 
//then create text files to send file attributes to.
//Future: Add the ability to also use these field attributes to update and 
//create the job folder on the website as well.

private void NewJob_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text);
        if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\0-Submittals"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\0-Submittals");
        if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\1-Pricing"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\1-Pricing");
        if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\2-Take Off"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\2-Take Off");
        if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\3-Files"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\3-Files");
        if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\4-Plans"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\4-Plans");
        if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\5-Specs"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\5-Specs");
        if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\6-Emails"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\6-Emails");
        if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\Properties"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\Properties");

        File.WriteAllText(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\Properties\Contact.txt", lblContact.Text);
        File.WriteAllText(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\Properties\JobName.txt", lblJobName.Text);
        File.WriteAllText(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\Properties\BidDate.txt", lblBidDate.Text);
        File.WriteAllText(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\Properties\Engineer.txt", lblEngineer.Text);
        File.WriteAllText(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\Properties\TakeOff.txt", lblTakeOff.Text);
        File.WriteAllText(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\Properties\Received.txt", lblReceived.Text);
        File.WriteAllText(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\Properties\Vendor.txt", lblVendor.Text);
        File.WriteAllText(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\Properties\Notes.txt", lblNotes.Text);

    }
```

Another problem is how do you remove this error when you right click on a web browser that is being used as a file explorer, without removing the fire wall. 
[Photo of the security Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7UZz.jpg)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

private void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (lblContact.Text.Contains("name0"))
            lblContact.Text.Replace("name0", "7");


        HtmlDocument doc = wbNewProject.Document;
        HtmlElement wbJobName = doc.GetElementById("Name"); //lblcontact.text
        HtmlElement wbEngineer = doc.GetElementById("engineer-lookup"); //
        HtmlElement wbSalesEng = doc.GetElementById("SalesEngineerUserId");
        HtmlElement wbLocation = doc.GetElementById("Location");
        HtmlElement wbBidDate = doc.GetElementById("BidDate");
        HtmlElement wbPriorApproval = doc.GetElementById("PriorApproval"); //True or False
        HtmlElement wbTakeOff = doc.GetElementById("TakeOffComplete"); //True or False
        HtmlElement wbProject = doc.GetElementById("RoleType"); //Design/Build or Plan/Spec
        wbJobName.SetAttribute("value", lblJobName.Text);

        if (lblContact.Text.Contains("Name1"))
            wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "2");
        if (lblContact.Text.Contains("name2"))
            wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "3");
        if (lblContact.Text.Contains("name3"))
            wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "4");
        if (lblContact.Text.Contains("name4"))
            wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "5");
        if (lblContact.Text.Contains("name5"))
            wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "6");
        if (lblContact.Text.Contains("name6"))
            wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "7");
        if (lblContact.Text.Contains("name7"))
            wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "10");
        if (lblContact.Text.Contains("name8"))
            wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "11");
        if (lblContact.Text.Contains("name9"))
            wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "12");

        wbLocation.SetAttribute("value", lblLocation.Text);
        wbBidDate.SetAttribute("value", lblBidDate.Text);

        if (lblPriorApp.Text.Contains("Yes"))
        wbPriorApproval.SetAttribute("value", "true");
        if (lblPriorApp.Text.Contains("No"))
            wbPriorApproval.SetAttribute("value", "false");
        if (lblTakeOff.Text.Contains("Done"))
        wbTakeOff.SetAttribute("value", "true");
        if (lblTakeOff.Text.Contains("Not Done"))
            wbTakeOff.SetAttribute("value", "false");

        wbEngineer.SetAttribute("value", lblEngineer.Text);
        wbProject.SetAttribute("value", lblProject.Text);
    }
```